# Implement owner draw menu bar MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, menubar, ownerdrawn

I want to create an owner draw menu bar (by menu bar I mean a bar that has the same width as the application window, not just to fit the menus) like the one in the image below

[image: Notice the menu item on the right and the background color for the bar that takes the full width of the window]

(Notice the menu item on the right and the background color for the bar that takes the full width of the window)

I only want the *buttons* to be customized (the size and the rectangle with a border on hover, and another effect when they're active), the menu popup itself has to be the Windows' default menu.

**What have I done so far?**

I managed to create the owner draw menu, but I have the following problems:

- the menu bar rectangle is only as wide as the widths of the items summed up (**I need it to take full window width**)
- all the menu items are styled uniformly (**I only want the *top buttons* to be styled like that**)

How can I get the desired look for my menu?

Comment: Don't. Use a menu-style toolbar instead. It's a heck of a lot easier.

Comment: Could you provide a possible implementation for such a toolbar, as answer, please?

Comment: For those curious, I figured out how to do this with some undocumented window messages. Works with themes and everything! https://github.com/adzm/win32-custom-menubar-aero-theme